# Overload resolution of modf

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a question for overload resolution of `modf`.

Consider the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    unsigned long ul = ULONG_MAX;
    long double ipart;
    long double fpart = std::modf(ul, &ipart);

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0)
        << ul << ", " << ipart << ", " << fpart << '\n'
        << static_cast<double>(ul) << '\n';
}
```

On my test environment, the code outputs...

```
18446744073709551615, 18446744073709551615, 0
18446744073709551616
```

cf. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7ZF2CwqEwBRU5hg4

C++14 standard 26.8[c.math] p.11 says,

> Moreover, there shall be additional overloads sufficient to ensure:
>
> 1. If any arithmetic argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `long double`, then all arithmetic arguments corresponding to
>      `double` parameters are effectively cast to `long double`.
> 2. Otherwise, if any arithmetic argument corresponding to a `double` parameter has type `double` or an integer type, then all arithmetic
>      arguments corresponding to `double` parameters are effectively cast to
>      `double`.
> 3. Otherwise, all arithmetic arguments corresponding to `double` parameters have type `float`.

The variable `ul` does not have type `long double` but integer type, so I think `ul` should be cast to
`double`, then `ipart` should be `18446744073709551616`.
(That is, GCC's behavior is wrong.)

Do I have a misunderstanding about this behavior?
(Of course, I think the GCC's behavior is more preferable.)

Comment: You are calling the `long double` variant of `std::modf` but your static cast is only done with `double`. "so I think ul should be cast to double": You're wrong, `ul` is cast to `long double`

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood what is happening here.

First of all let's check what `ul` is going to be cast to, by passing it as the only parameter into `std::modf`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    unsigned long ul = ULONG_MAX;
    auto fpart = std::modf(ul, nullptr);

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0)
        << ul << ", " << ipart;
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
prog.cc:9:46: error: call of overloaded 'modf(long unsigned int&, std::nullptr_t)' is ambiguous
...
/usr/local/gcc-head/include/c++/7.0.0/cmath:376:3: note: candidate: float std::modf(float, float*)
...
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:116:1: note: candidate: double modf(double, double*)
...
/usr/local/gcc-head/include/c++/7.0.0/cmath:380:3: note: candidate: long double std::modf(long double, long double*)
...
```

As you can see the compiler can't decide which of the 3 overloaded functions to call, as it doesn't know which one you want from the parameters you pass.

So why does you example compile?

Check out the second paremeter you pass: A pointer to `long double ipart;`.
So that`s something the compiler can work with.

Is there any function taking a `long double *` as second parameter? Yes there is:

`long double modf( long double x, long double* iptr );`

So what your code does here is more or less something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <climits>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    unsigned long ul = ULONG_MAX;
    long double ipart;
    long double fpart = std::modf(static_cast<long double>(ul), &ipart);

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(0)
        << ul << ", " << ipart << ", " << fpart << '\n'
        << static_cast<double>(ul) << '\n';
}
```

As you can see now is that you are comparing `static_cast<long double>(ul)` with `static_cast<double>(ul)`.

Comment: I know why my sample behaves as above, and I know that libstdc++ has no additional overload corresponding to 26.8[c.math] p.11 (I saw cmath header file).
My question is why libstdc++ has no additional overload corresponding to 26.8[c.math] p.11.

Comment: @MitsuruKariya what overload are you talking about? There are 3 overloads for each of the 3 cases. You just assumed the wrong one.

Comment: For example, std::cos has more than 3 overloads, for double, for float, for long double, and for other arithmetic types (corresponding to 26.8[c.math] p.11).  So, I think that std::modf  should have more than 3 overloads. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/nQuanLrInfQEdey9

Comment: So you want a `std::modf` for a `std::complex`, `std::valarray` and integral types (which are cast to double)? What exactly would be the use case for these? `modf` is for floating point values (that's where the "f" comes from). `valarray` is not necessarily using floating point values and integral types don't make sense to pass to `modf`. And why would you want to pass a `complex` to `modf` - that doesn't really have a use case, does it? And if you need this special case you can still use `modf`on the real part of the complex.

Comment: @MitsuruKariya Short version: Because the overloads are unecessary.

Comment: I couldn't care less about any use cases.  I only want to know what the standard says.

Comment: Let me get this straight: You are posting a question with a faulty example (or at least misunderstood by you). You append the part that describes the 3 types of overload that a function in 'c.math' has to provide - all of which are provided by `std::modf`. Then you ask why it does not have more overloads - which I answered. If you want to go more into detail about what the standard says: READ IT YOURSELF!